# Jump to a hidden section on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a 3 groups of content in a page that can be navigated through tabs. There's a default visible tab when I enter the page and then I can click the tabs to hide the current content and show the other.

**example.html**

```
<a href="example" name="example" class="tab active">Example</a> // default
<a href="about" name="about" class="tab">About</a>
<a href="contact" name="contact" class="tab">...</a>

...

<div class="example visible" id="example">...</div> // default visible content
<div class="about" id="about">...</div>
<div class="contact" id="contact">...</div>
```

Now, I added a footer where there are links connecting to the 3 tabs. So, if I am in a different part of the site, I can click a link, say, *About Me*, that would navigate to **example.html** and straight to the section *About Me*.

**footer.html**

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="/example">Example</a></li>
   <li><a href="/example#about">Example About</a></li>
   <li><a href="/example#contact">Example Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

The above works perfectly fine. **But here's the problem**, when I click on the footer links *while* I am on example.html, it jumps to the position of the content but it cannot be seen because the current tab is still active. Is there a way to check the url whenever it changes so I can parse it and change the active tab based on it?

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// find which footer link was clicked; doesn't work when navigating on the same page
  var hash = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('#') + 1);

if(hash === "foundation") {
     $("a[name='foundation']").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("
active");
     $(".foundation").addClass("visible").siblings().removeClass("visible");
}
else if(hash === "credits") {...}
...



// click event for tabs
  $("a").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    var currentAttrVal = $(this).attr("href");
    $("." + currentAttrVal).addClass("visible").siblings().removeClass("visible");
  });
});
```

I know the script is too repetitive, but I'll refactor everything once I sort this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the location object has its own property for the current hash

`window.location.hash`

this includes the hash sign too so you need

`window.location.hash.slice(1)`

For listening to the change of the hash you will have to use the `onhashchange` event

You can use one of the following techniques

```
window.onhashchange = funcRef;
```

or

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", funcRef, false);
```

This way is used in frameworks like angular when they use the #! way of defining routes for browsers that do not support the History API

You can read more about it to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange)

Answer (score 0):

Here the concept which i think may help you: ([jsfiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/layonez/c3byxcbn/))

**footer.html**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="button" class="navigateButton" value="example" onclick="navigate(value)">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="button" class="navigateButton" value="About" onclick="navigate(value)">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="button" class="navigateButton" value="Contact" onclick="navigate(value)">
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.navigateButton {
  background: none!important;
  border: none;
  padding: 0!important;
  font: inherit;
  /*border is optional*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JS**

```
var navigate = function (value) {

  switch (value) {
    case "example":
    //select appropriate tab here
      window.location.replace('/example');
      break;
    case "About":
    //select appropriate tab here
      window.location.replace('/example#About');
      break;      
    case "Contact":
    //select appropriate tab here
    window.location.replace('/example#Contact');
    break;
    default:
      alert('Unknown type');
  }
}
```